# Syncronize keytimes of audio and video by adding automatic pauses

Tags: ffmpeg

I would to ask for help regarding this matter. I am a beginner in the use of FMMPEG and I want to know if it is possible to perform the algorithm to edit a video file with an audio file.

Let's suppose that you have an Audio and Video clips.
The Audio has a keytimes on 0s, 5s and 11s and the Video has a keytimes on 0s, 3s, and 16s. This keytimes are in the following TXT file:

```
Audio   Video
0s      0s        Audio and video playback starts.
5s      3s        (1)
11s     16s       (2)
```

The algorithm takes in the input an Audio clip, Video clip and the TXT file, I want (automaticaly) compute pauses and sync clips according to the following explanation:

(1) During the first 5 seconds of audio, the first 3 seconds of video are played. Since the video lasts less than the audio, a 2 second pause should be inserted after the 3rd second of video (to match the 5 second video's length).

(2) From the second 5 to second 11 the audio is played, from second 3 to 16 the video will be played at the same time. Since the audio´s length will be 6 seconds and the video's length will be 13 seconds, a 7 second pause should be added to the video.

I have read and searched a lot about this, but I haven't found anything that helps me to start this algorithm. Could you help me, please?

I apologize in advance if it is a duplicated ask.

Answer (score 0):

The [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) can help you do this.

First, split the video and audio streams at the designated points and reset timestamps. Then concat them. Let's use the timings in your example.

```
 Audio   Video
0s      0s        Audio and video playback starts.
5s      3s        (1)
11s     16s       (2)
```

So,

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio
-filter_complex "[0]split=2[v1][v2];
                 [1]asplit=2[a1][a2];
                 [v1]trim=0:3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
                 [v2]trim=3:16,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
                 [a1]atrim=0:5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
                 [a2]atrim=5:11,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
                 [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1"
output.mp4
```

The concat filter will use the longest stream in each segment pair (`[vn][an]`) and elongate the shorter stream with silence (audio) or pause (video).